# How to uninstall Hbase from Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, hadoop

I had installed HBase -0.94 in my Ubuntu system.

I want to uninstall it now. I tried,

```
sudo apt-get purge hadoop-hbase
```

but it shows `unable to locate package`.

Help me uninstall it.

Comment: "I had installed HBase-0.94" How did you install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the apache version from their [website](http://hbase.apache.org/) you downloaded a "tar.gz" file and extracted it into your system. Ubuntu Software Center will know nothing about your installation so `apt-get` is not the correct method.

Uninstalling it is equal to removing the directory you extracted it into. So open a terminal, navigate to the directory you extracted it into and remove the directory "hbase-0.94.20/".

---

Let us assume you extracted the software in "Downloads" in your "Home". Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T

```
cd ~/Downloads
rm -rf hbase-0.94.20/
exit
```

Comment: I didn't just unzip it. I followed all the steps from the apache official documentation to run Hbase in standalone mode. ( http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart ) Would removing the directory work then too?

Comment: Yes see 1.2.1 in that link. Removing that dir is enough. My latest edit should be enough BUT the 1st command will probably be different for you (I doubt you would extract it in ~/Downloads)